# How can add CSS file to CUSTOM WIDGET in Magento?

Tags: javascript, css, magento, widget

So, I have **custom widget** for **Magento** (like slideshow for products).

And want add custom **CSS / Javascript** to my widget.

I do not want show(load) CSS / JS file every time.

---

***I want load JS/CSS ONLY when PAGE include The Custom Widget.***

Thanks.

Comment: If there is a particular kind of page type where the widget is included you can add the js only in the concerned layout. Where would you show your widget ?

Comment: I want insert the widget  on any page type.
And want add custom JS/CSS only if widget is included on page.
I not want edit layout XML for every type of  page. 



So, I  still in  finding solutions for JS/CSS  for  Magento widget.
But  think that Magento, have not solutions for my ideas.

:(

Answer (score 4):

This depends if you have added your widget as a widget instance (CMS -> Widgets) or have included it in the content area of a page, static block or email like so: `{{widget type="blabla/carousel"}}`.

If you have included it as a widget instance, you can add your assets like so:

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    if ($head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) { 
        $head->addCss('myfile.css');
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

..in your block that implements `Mage_Widget_Block_Interface`.

(see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/212110/)

AFAIK, it's impossible to add assets when you include the widget inline as a template directive. This is simply because the HTML head has already outputted it's HTML: The template directives (such as `{{widget}}` or `{{var}}`) are being noticed in the _toHtml stage of the block. Calling any method on a block that has already been rendered won't have any effect.

Also see the `$processor->filter` call in the `_toHtml` method in `Mage_Cms_Block_Page`

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
    $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
    $processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
    $html = $processor->filter($this->getPage()->getContent());
    $html = $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() . $html;
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is fairly old, but in case there is anyone that is looking for a way to add CSS or javascript only when the magento widget is included(without requiring that it be a "widget instance" as in the answer given by Erfan) I would recommend using a small ajax script in your phtml template file. If your design package does not use jQuery then your code may be different.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.when(
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/myWidget.css');?>",
        success: function(data){
            jQuery("head").append("<style>" + data + "</style>");
        },
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
    }),
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/myWidget.js');?>",
        dataType: "script",
        cache: false,
    })

).then(function(){
        myWidget.setupFunction();
    });   
});
```